# Detecting if a style is a user style

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

After calling `window.getComputedStyle`, how can I tell whether a style a style is from the page itself (rather than being from the browser)? I'm interested in doing so in pure javascript, though I would settle for a solution which ran in the context of an add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a hard time figuring out where the rules that `getComputedStyle` gives you came from. Note that the code provided by MaxArt isn't a complete solution - there are also inherited styles so one would have to repeat everything for parent nodes. The simpler approach would be using [`inIDOMUtils.getCSSStyleRules()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/inIDOMUtils#getCSSStyleRules%28%29), along these lines:

```js
function isPageStyle(styleSheet)
{
  if (styleSheet.ownerNode)
    return true;

  if (styleSheet.ownerRule instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIDOMCSSImportRule)
    return isPageStyle(styleSheet.parentStyleSheet);

  return false;
}

var domUtils = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/inspector/dom-utils;1"]
                         .getService(Components.interfaces.inIDOMUtils);
var rules = domUtils.getCSSStyleRules(element);
for (var i = 0; i < rules.Count(); i++)
{
  var rule = rules.GetElementAt(i);
  if (isPageStyle(rule.parentStyleSheet))
    alert(rule.cssText);
}
```

You will have to do it for the parent nodes as well. For a complete example you can look at the [implementation of the Inspector feature in Firefox](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/64187d60fae7/browser/devtools/styleinspector/CssRuleView.jsm#l121) (`isPageStyle` function in my answer shamelessly "borrowed" from [here](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/64187d60fae7/browser/devtools/styleinspector/CssLogic.jsm#l844)).

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but it explains what I would need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to parse every stylesheet in the document, you can't. If you have issues with the style every browser applies to the elements by default, you can rely on something like Reset CSS.

If you want to parse the stylesheets, anyway, you can do something like this:

```
function isDefaultStyle(element, property) {
    if (element.style[property]) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, r; j < document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; j++) {
            r = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j];
            if (element.matchesSelector(r.selectorText) && r[property]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`matchesSelector` is an element method that isn't actually supported by any browsers, which actually support namespaced functions like `webkitMatchesSelector`, `mozMatchesSelector`, `oMatchesSelector` and even `msMatchesSelector` (IE9+). Sadly, for IE8 you have to emulate it and I couldn't find anything better than checking if the elements is contained in `document.querySelectorAll(r.selectorText)`, which can be very slow for large DOM trees.

In this last case, you also obviously have to use `rules` instead of `cssRules`.